# How can I switch the activity of the content of a tab in Tabhost

Tags: android

I have created a TabHost and in 1 of the tab, I have added the content using

```
 mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
                .setIndicator(getString(R.string.dialerIconLabel),
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_dialer))
                .setContent(intent));
```

Is it possible for me to switch the content's activity programatically after I called 'addTab of TabHost'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot readily change what `View` is the content of the tab. However, that `View` could be a `ViewFlipper`, or a `FrameLayout` with only one visible child, which can give you a similar visual effect.

Comment: Does that mean that I call multiple setContent() (each with a different View) will not work?

Comment: As far as I know, multiple TabHost.TabSpec#setContent() calls will not work.

Comment: so still no answer for this quesion?